# Converting to an usable array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, push

I am trying to convert this loaded DOM to an array format which I can use.

```
<div>
    <div>[a image]</div>
    <div>
        <p class="ab">text 1</p>
        <p class="bc">text 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>[a image]</div>
    <div>
        <p class="ab">text 1</p>
        <p class="bc">text 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I Would like to read these div nodes and convert it to an array structure like so:

> var arrayObj = [{
>                                                             "img" : "source",                                                    "ab" : "text",                                      "bc" : "text"                                                  }, {        "img" : "source",
>   "ab" : "text",                                         "bc" : "text"      }

Could someone please tell me how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by HTML data? Is it loaded in the DOM? Is it actual HTML text?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Yes it is loaded in the DOM.

@ Matt Ball - I havn't tried anything yet, i am very new to javascript and jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the container's `children[]` array. For each one, find the image and the `p` tags. Assign to a new Object. Push the Object into an array.

Example:

```
var out = [], container = document.getElementById('container'),
    c = container.children, l = c.length, i, obj, p, m, j;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    obj = {};
    obj.img = c[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
    p = c[i].getElementsByTagName('p');
    m = p.length;
    for( j=0; j<m; j++) obj[p[j].className] = p[j].firstChild.nodeValue;
    out[i] = obj;
}
// out
```

Comment: Hi Kolink, that worked perfectly but I have this other issue. I am trying to assign a value to each p.length, the data array should look like: 
{
[a image],
title: text 1,
description: text 2}

Is there any small tweaks I can do to achieve this?

Comment: It should work already... What's it giving you that's wrong?

Comment: As of now the script is only getting the content of p, but I wanted to assign each content of p to its relative class name. so the array will be like so ||| var out = { "img" : "http//source",
"p.ab" : "text", "p.bc" : "text" }

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do... I have it looping through the `<p>` elements, getting their class name and their content, and adding it to the object...

Comment: Its now working - sorry I was testing this on jsFiddle...duh!

Comment: I have another problem now...this script works fine in all major browsers but I am getting this error on IE8 = [Unable to get value of the property 'src': object is null or undefined] I have tried to put this script on "document.ready", "$().ready(function" and other elegant methods...its 3am and I have no idea how to solve this!!!